# Transform csv to data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

I have a huge csv with rows like this:

```
ColumnA=valueA,ColumnB=valueB
ColumnA=valueABC,ColumnB=valueBC
```

So header and value in one line.
How can I make a dataframe in R that looks like this at the end:

```
ColumnA   ColumnB
valueA    valueB
valueABC  valueBC
```

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 4):

convert to a `dcf` file:

```
read.dcf(textConnection(paste(chartr("=,", ":\n",
            readLines('file.csv')), collapse="\n\n")), all = TRUE)

   ColumnA ColumnB
1   valueA  valueB
2 valueABC valueBC
```

---

Same code in a logical flow:

```
readLines('file.csv')|>
    chartr("=,", ':\n', x=_) |>
    paste(collapse = '\n\n') |>
    textConnection() |>
    read.dcf(all = TRUE)

   ColumnA ColumnB
1   valueA  valueB
2 valueABC valueBC
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also convert to a json file:

```
readLines('file.csv')|>
    gsub("([^=,]+)=([^,]+)", '"\\1":"\\2"', x = _)|>
    paste0("{", x=_, "}", collapse=",") |>
    sprintf("[%s]", x=_) |>
    jsonlite::fromJSON()

   ColumnA ColumnB
1   valueA  valueB
2 valueABC valueBC
```

Comment: Dang - you just beat me to that option ;-) - JSON does seem faster.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that you have a 'huge csv', I thought I'd see if I could speed things up a bit by using the *jsonlite* package after some formatting changes similar to the `read.dcf` option by @Onyambu:

```
## 100K rows of 26 columns
txt <- rep(paste(paste0("Column", LETTERS, "=", "value"), collapse=","), 1e5)
txt <- paste(txt, collapse="\n")

library(jsonlite)
system.time({
    rl <- readLines(textConnection(txt))
    rl <- paste0("{\"", rl, "\"}")
    rl <- gsub(",", "\",\"", rl)
    rl <- gsub("=", "\":\"", rl)
    out <- stream_in(textConnection(rl))
})
## Imported 1e+05 records. Simplifying...
##   user  system elapsed 
##   6.45    0.05    6.50 


system.time({
out <- read.dcf(textConnection(paste(chartr("=,", ":\n",
            readLines(textConnection(txt))), collapse="\n\n")), all = TRUE)
})
##   user  system elapsed 
##  24.65    0.44   25.11
```

Comment: This is going back and forth. Probably consider not benchmarking readLines as whatever the cause you will still have to do so. Maybe use `data.table::fread/readr::read_lines` for speed on that part. As that will be the same for both codes. Benchmark the code after that